# Creating EXE using flex and air from visualstudio using ensemble tufino

Tags: apache-flex

I need to know how can we create a exe using flex and air from visual studio using ensemble tufino.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do it through Visual Studio but Ive gone 
through the process before for [converting Air app to Exe](http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/adobe-air-2beta-2-to-exe-packaging-air-app-in-windows-executable/).